# Google Sheet Sum Row: Count if above or below criteria

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to create a summary row in a google sheet that tallies up how many cells met their criteria.  These criterion are set in 2 columns to the left; Column C is the "Goal" column, which has the goal number. Column D is the "MinMax" column, which determines if that goal number is the min or max.

For example, if the Goal is 5 and the MinMax is Max, then the goal is 5 or less (5 being the maximum number allowed).

I already have successfully created conditional formatting for this sheet, which looks like the following:

=IF($D4="Min",E4>=$C4,E4<=$C4)  |  Turn cell green

I am struggling to find a way to use a similar calculation for the Summary row.  I feel like I might need an array formula, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the values try:

```
=if(D2="Max",countif(E2:E,">="&C2),countif(E2:E,"<="&C2))
```

If you want to sum them useL

```
=if(D2="Max",sumif(E2:E,">="&C2),SUMIF(E2:E,"<="&C2))
```

Comment: This got me a good chunk of the way there--but I don't think it's calculating line by line.  There are 15 rows, and in the first column, the total number should be 11, but it's showing 7.  It looks like it's only using the top row of column C to compare, rather than each row of C.

I feel like it should almost be something like:

=if($D4:$D19="Max",countif(E$4:E$19,"<="&$C4:$C19),countif(E$4:E$19,">="&$C4:$C19))

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of you data?

Comment: Are you wanting to get a count for each row like this?https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ux8QRq7lPLJ7W0BpRu4XyfJeTVksrTFv1iEVzt8GQE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not quite.  I need a count at the bottom (for each date column) of how many rows met their respective goal.  I edited your sheet a little bit to show what I mean.

Comment: I think I have it. Could you share the actual sheet instead of just an image so I can test it. Thanks.

Comment: Check the spreadsheet I linked again. I used a user defined function to count cells from your conditional formatting logic.

Comment: I looked at your sheet, but it's taking a long time to load the function.

Just to confirm--there's no (good) way to do this through a formula?  Gotta be a function?

Comment: I haven't found a way. This is much faster and will expand as you add piople or dates. It runs on open or from the custom menu:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eQmAYc1bpv-At8vpUygRbIyj1oH919YAKZ0GCWn9JpE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I actually figured out a formula!!  Here, check this scary thing out:  
  
=countif(ARRAYFORMULA(if($D$4:$D$19="Min",E$4:E$19>=$C$4:$C$19,$C$4:$C$19>=E$4:E$19)),true)-countif(E4:E19,"N/A")  
  
I had to go back into the data and change the blank cells to "N/A" to make it work, but it works!!

Comment: Great job. I made a slight mod to the third if parm and can handle blanks w/o N/A. =ArrayFormula(countif(if($D$4:$D$19="Min",E4:E19>=$C$4:$C$19,E4:E19<=$C$4:$C$19),true))

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a formula!!

```
=countif(ARRAYFORMULA(if($D$4:$D$19="Min",E$4:E$19>=$C$4:$C$‌​19,$C$4:$C$19>=E$4:E‌​$19)),true)-countif(‌​E4:E19,"N/A")
```

I had to go back into the data and change the blank cells to "N/A" to make it work, but it works!!